# Hassidut for Non-Mystics

Tags: sources-mekorot, product-recommendation, mysticism-kabbalah, chasidut-hasidism

I have difficulty connecting to mysticism. Can anyone recommend a hassidic thinker or a work of Hassidut that would be appealing to someone who is not into mysticism?

Comment: Why do you want to connect to mysticism?

Comment: I don't think you can connect to Hassidus without mysticism. It is all based on supernatural revelations from God/Elijah/angels to Hassidic figures. They do not think logically and don't deduct their conclusions from existing Rabbinic literature. It's a "take it or leave it" approach - you either believe your Rebbe and his divinity or you don't. Some renowned Hassidic figures dealt with non-spiritual/cosmological issues, i.g. Halacha, such as Aruch Hashulchan, but it has nothing to do with Hassidut.

Comment: @AlBerko Aruch HaShulchan was not at all Hasidic

Comment: I want to give this area of Judaism an honest try, but mystical concepts do not resonate with me.

Comment: Also, many Rabbis insist that hassidut is based on the words of Hazal. I love the works of Hazal and am deeply touched by them, so I am wondering if I am missing something here and just not understanding hassidut.

Comment: There is no obligation to connect to mysticism per se. Stick to the words of Chazal for now and you'll be fine. Trying to force it is not wise.

Comment: Pachad Yitzchak / Michtav Me'Eliyahu / Ohr Gedlayahu / Noam Elimelech

Comment: @pcoz The first two may have been influenced by some chassidism, but they are de facto members of the Litvish mussar movement.

Comment: There is an expression mentioned often in the teachings of the Alter Rebbe, author of the Tanya, which translates roughly as, "Each one according to how their soul is rooted Above." This idea is also found in the teachings of the Ari z"l, Rabbi Yosef Tziyach and many others. If, as you say, you feel no draw toward the mystical side of Torah, including Chassidut, It may not be for you. In this day, the best advice, generally, is to pursue what you are drawn toward. If, for you, that is Niglah, invest your energy there. May G-d bless you with success.

Comment: @N.T. I don't think Rav Hutner agrees with you, and one of Rb Dessler's primary rebbeim was a Chabad chassid.

Comment: @pcoz Rav Hutner was a prominent member of the Slabodka products who became Roshei Yeshiva in America. Slabodka is from a Misnaged tradition. Rav Dessler also studied chassidus, but again he was a prominent member of the Mussar tradition. Having a Chabad rebbi does not make you chassidish.

Comment: @N.T. The Sefer Ha'Zichronos says that Rav Hutner said about himself that he was not *shayach* to any *chevrah* or *sug*. He was very *chassidish* and used to *fier tisch*. Litvaks do not *fier tisch*. Rb Dessler was more of a thoroughbred Litvak, but his *Toros* are obviously a synthesis of *mussar* and *chassidus*, so if the questioner wants to know where to get an intellectual take on *chassidus*, then that is the right address.

Comment: @pcoz I know many Litvaks who make an oneg shabbos. It is pretty much similar to a tish, just a rose by another name.

Comment: @N.T. While wearing a *spodek* and a *bekishe*?

Comment: Bekishes are more comfortable than jackets, so yes.

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly recommend reading (the free version of the work) "The key to Kabbalah", written by Rabbi Nissan Dovid Dubov. [The work is available online at Chabad.org](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/361868/jewish/The-Key-to-Kabbalah.htm).

[The Lubavitcher Rebbe explains in his letter (10th of Nissan, 5741)](https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/letters/default_cdo/aid/380155/jewish/On-Jewish-Mysticism.htm) that Jewish Mysticism has to do with the two facets of the Torah, 1) the revealed part of the Torah and, 2) the hidden part of the Torah, also known as Pnimiyut HaTorah.

> Mysticism, in general, has a variety of connotations, but Jewish mysticism must necessarily be defined in terms of specific topics that have to do with the Nistar of Torah—one of the two primary facets of the Torah: Nigleh and Nistar, the revealed and the hidden. Needless to say, there can be no dichotomy between the two, because it is One Torah, given by One G‑d, to the “one people on earth.”
>
> Jewish mysticism helps to realize the said purpose of the soul by teaching it how to recognize the spirituality of matter, and that in every physical thing, even in the inanimate, there is a “soul,” which is the creative force that has created it—a being out of non-being—and continuously keeps [it] from reverting back to its former state of non-existence.

Good luck with learning Pnimiyut HaTorah, in this case Mysticism. And, as the Rebbe writes ([Letter from 24th of Marcheshvan, 5720](https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/letters/default_cdo/aid/1872927/jewish/Learning-Chassidism-Gives-Ability-to-Believe.htm)):

> Incidentally, let me add that the Vilner Gaon (not only the Baal HaTanya, mind you) writes that those who do not learn Pnimius HaTorah prolong the Golus and delay the Geulo, and that without knowledge of Pnimius HaTorah it is impossible to know properly Nigle of Torah.

Also, the second source I would recommend you is reading the Kuntres Eitz HaChayim, written by the Rebbe Rashab (Rabbi Sholom Dovber Schneersohn from Lubavitch). The Kuntres can be viewed online [here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/144473/jewish/The-Tree-of-Life-Kuntres-Eitz-HaChayim.htm).

[In the overview from this Kuntres](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/144474/jewish/Overview.htm), it is explained that this Kuntres included extensive quotes from Kabbalistic texts, such as quotes from the Zohar.

> Kuntres Etz HaChayim, employs far more technical wording than many other Chassidic sources. There are extensive quotes from the Zohar, the Etz HaChayim, and other Kabbalistic texts, as well as passages from the Talmud and the Midrash. The Rebbe Rashab begins with an abstract Chassidic concept, proceeds to develop its practical applications, and then, on the basis of these theoretical constructs, gives direct, pointed advice to the students of the yeshivah.

Comment: Thank you very much for these resources.

Comment: Such a great idea to give resources for connecting to mysticism +1

Comment: See also end of derech eitz chaim from ramchal

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the teachings of the Rebbe Simcha Bunim Bonhardt, the second Grand Rebbe of Peshischa. He was a Hassidic leader that was highly critical of the emphasis on mysticism, the miraculous, veneration of leaders, etc. He taught a philosophy emphasizing critical thought, individuality and authenticity in ones relationship with God. There is a pretty good English language book on him, [The Quest for Authenticity](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9655240037), and here's the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simcha_Bunim_of_Peshischa). Though he was somewhat controversial in his day, his teachings are considered foundational to many different Hasidic sects extant today.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest you try the sefer Nesivos Shalom. It is a great sefer, which brings different parts of the Torah from every week's parshah to life in a beautiful way. It isn't very Kabbalistic, and any Kabbalistic ideas which he brings, he explains very well. You should also look into other seforim from this Rebbe. Including on many Festivals and on the whole spectrum of Jewish thought. It isn't considered the most hassidic sefer. However, it has a very hassidic feel. It was authored by The Slonimer Rebbe.

Additionally, I would suggest you listen to the classes given by Rabbi YY Jacobson. Especially the ones in which he explains different teachings of hassidism in an extremely easy to understand practical way. His website is [theyeshiva.net](https://theyeshiva.net).

There is also [Harav Moshe Weinberger](https://www.torahanytime.com/#/speaker?l=786), [Rabbi Joey Rosenfeld,](https://www.youtube.com/user/joro230/videos) [Rabbi Yussie Zakutinskty](https://www.torahanytime.com/#/speaker?l=325) and others. I gave links to each of them.

The main thing to remember is that the one thing which is greater than all of the deepest Torah, is a simple Jew with a true yearning and desire to connect to Hashem. As one of the founding ideas of hassidic thought, which is brought from our sages, "Rachmana liba bo'ei". All Hashem desires is ones heart.

Hashem should give you Hatzlacha in everything you do. And may you merit to constantly come closer to him, through your Neshama and through our Tzaddikim.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend a central and fundamental book of Hassidut: TANYA. Here is a link for translation plus explanations (Lesson in Tanya): https://www.chabad.org/library/tanya/tanya_cdo/aid/6237/jewish/Lessons-in-Tanya.htm

Since you want something appealing that is not mysticism, maybe start by learning the 3rd part of Tanya called Igeret HaTeshuva, very practical.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you.